# Firebase Phone Authentication error in React Native Code

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to build a React Native app and firebase authentication. I am getting the Error:

> RecaptchaVerifier is only supported in a browser HTTP/HTTPS environment with DOM support

```
auth
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(number, appVerifier)) // <- this is where captcha is added
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ confirm: result });
        this.setState({ buttonText: "Verify OTP" });
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error in phone auth: ${err}`);
      });
```

The version which I am using of firebase is `"react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0"`
When I remove second parameter it gives an error which states two parameter required, found one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using `react-native-firebase` phone auth with 5.X.X version. You can skip the appverifier from the method and instead use the following method from `react-native-firebase`. It will automatically open a window to verify the app and recaptha.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
.then(confirmResult => // save confirm result to use with the manual verification code)
.catch(error => /error);
```

Comment: Yes my firebase version is `5.6.0` and when I removed the appVerifier it says required 2 arguments but got one

Comment: @SandipSingh - did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ChrisEaheart - yes I did I updated my firebase version and it works like a charm incase u need help regarding anything lemme know

Comment: @SandipSingh -  My package.json has the following - are you referring to a different package?:     "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.7.1",

Comment: earlier i was using version 5 now i m using version 6 which is current latest version and it doesn't invoke any issue

Comment: @ChrisEaheart you can post your code over here and I can help you out with that